# Process creation tree for this code?

Tags: process, posix, fork

What's the process creation tree for this code (assuming all forks succeed)?

```
if(fork())
    fork();
n = 3;
for(i=1;i<n;++i)
{
    if(pid = fork())
        break;
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
        [0]
         |
         /\
     [1]    [1]
      |      |
     [2]    [2]
      |      |
     [3]    [3]
      |
     [4]
```

But that wasn't even one of the choices! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First line:

```
if (fork())
```

After this fork, there are two processes, the parent and the child. In the parent, fork() returns nonzero. In the child, fork() returns zero. This means that the next line will run only in the parent.

```
    fork();
```

The parent forks again. Now there are three processes, and all three will run the rest of the code.

```
for(i=1;i<n;++i)
{
    if(pid = fork())
        break;
}
```

First, i=1. Each of the three processes creates a child, sees a nonzero result, and breaks out of the loop.  So the original three processes are done. But the children will keep going.

Next time through the loop, i=2. The same thing happens. Each of the three child process forks off a child of its own, sees a nonzero result, and breaks. The three new children will keep going.

And so on up to i=n-1.

I'll spare you my attempts at ASCII art, but the resulting tree looks a bit like a certain familiar piece of silverware...